# JQ return exit boolean instead of exit status code

Tags: json, grep, jq, exit-code

I have following script

```
grep -e . testFile |
jq -e ".fundingMoved.\"com.test\".map.\"java.util.HashMap\" |

if .TRANSACTION_DESTINATION? then
(.AGREEMENT_OWNING_ORG | startswith(\"MXN\")) and (.TRANSACTION_DESTINATION |startswith(\"BRL\")) or
(.AGREEMENT_OWNING_ORG | startswith(\"MXN\")) and (.TRANSACTION_DESTINATION |startswith(\"CAD\")) or
(.AGREEMENT_OWNING_ORG | startswith(\"MXN\")) and (.TRANSACTION_DESTINATION |startswith(\"USD\"))
else
(.AGREEMENT_OWNING_ORG | startswith(\"USD\")) and (.WAREHOUSE |startswith(\"AUD\")) or
(.AGREEMENT_OWNING_ORG | startswith(\"USD\")) and (.WAREHOUSE |startswith(\"AED\")) or
(.AGREEMENT_OWNING_ORG | startswith(\"USD\")) and (.WAREHOUSE |startswith(\"EGP\"))

end"
```

If testFile has match then i am seeing `true` and if no match then i am seeing `false`

I am using this script in some legacy system so it is taking only grep as argument so i am using grep along with jq.

Even though jq return `false`, somehow grep is interpreting that as match and perform action.

I tried with `-e` still i am seeing true/false instead of exit status

what i am trying to do ?

My grep should return right status code.

If my condition is true in Jq then  my grep should success and if my jq return false then my grep exit code should be non zero.

How do i return exit status code from `jq` instead of `true/false`. Currently `jq` is returning true or false hence grep is considering everything as match.

Comment: RE "*Even though jq return false some how grep is interpreting that as match and perform action.*", No. In the command you posted, grep receives absolutely nothing from jq.

Comment: Re "*If my condition is true in Jq then my grep should success and if my jq return false then my grep exit code should be non zero.*", It can't possibly do that. The `grep` will literally finish executing before `jq`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *How do i return exit status code from `jq` instead of true/false.*

This is what the `-e` command line switch it used.

> `-e` / `--exit-status:`
>
> Sets the exit status of jq to 0 if the last output values was neither `false` nor `null`, 1 if the last output value was either `false` or `null`, or 4 if no valid result was ever produced. Normally jq exits with 2 if there was any usage problem or system error, 3 if there was a jq program compile error, or 0 if the jq program ran.

Since the specific test is irrelevant, I'm going to use the simpler `type == "string"` test in my examples.

```
$ jq -e 'type == "string"' <<<'"abc"'
true

$ echo $?
0

$ jq -e 'type == "string"' <<<'123'
false

$ echo $?
1
```

Note that while the documentation suggests that `jq -e` exits with `4` when no input is provided, it actually exits with `0`.

```
$ jq -e 'type == "string"' </dev/null

$ echo $?
0
```

But it's simple to change that by using `-n` and `inputs`.

```
$ jq -en 'inputs | type == "string"' <<<'"abc"'
true

$ echo $?
0

$ jq -en 'inputs | type == "string"' <<<'123'
false

$ echo $?
1

$ jq -en 'inputs | type == "string"' </dev/null

$ echo $?
4
```

Redirect the output (e.g. using `>/dev/null`) if you don't want to see the output.

---

`halt_error` also allows you to set the exit code, and it gives more control over the exit code produced. But it's more complicated to use, and it suffers from the same problem with empty inputs, and it doesn't have a simple workaround.

```bash
jq -s '
   if length == 0 then
      null | halt_error(1)
   else
      .[] |
      if type == "string" then
         null | halt_error(0)
      else
         null | halt_error(1)
      end
   end
'
```